# Zend HTML Link to file above $baseUrl

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

I am trying to create an html link in the head section of a page, to a `/node_modules/` file which is outside of the /public directory. The `$baseUrl` is `/public`.

How can i create a link to a file which is not in the /public directory?

I have tried the usual relative path (../) but obviously this does not work and php is required to solve this.

The directory structure is as follows:-

```
/siteroot    
    /node_modules/
    /public
```

Example current link:-

```
<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/node_modules/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
```

but this will look for /node_modules/ inside of public, which is not whats required.

Comment: You could (hack it), but you should not. By default, ONLY the `public/` directory is accessible from outside your application, ie by end-users. Giving end-users access to the project code _should_ give you the creeps. If you need resources made available which you included in your project with node, than you should compile them to the public directory, using Node.js. Lookup how to use "node.js package.json" (the latter is config). But don't give end-users access to **anything** outside of the public directory. They don't need it and it's just a plain security risk.

Comment: Thanks @rkeet. I never intended to open up the project code to the public. I only wanted to know how to link the file via php.

Comment: `I am trying to create an html link in the head section of a page, to a /node_modules/ file` -> that bit says you're attempting to create a link (say `<a href="node_modules/jquery/jquery.js">jquery link</a>`). That's client-side access. Really, look up the compile options. Compiling what and how you need will create the necessary node_module assets you've configured in your `public/` folder, eliminating the need for this hack you're asking about.

Comment: And stackoverflow continues to be the harshest place to ask for help on the internet! Somebody marked the question down :o

Comment: @LeeColarelli Not at all, but some people enjoy to marked down unnecessarily rather than providing some suggestions. of course stackoverflow is a best plateform for experience as well freshers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getcwd()`, this will return a path to project directory, i.e "`/siteroot`", as current working directory.

So now you can use it as

```
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>/node_modules/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
```

Comment: Thank you @Gautam Rai. Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: There's a reason `$this->basePath()` returns the `public/` folder: it's publicly accessible. You deploy something where this answer works into production and the same level will be (by default, unless you get creative with rules on the server itself) accessible. So, next to `node_modules/` there's `module/`, which, of course, contains the source code of the application. There's also `config/` on that same level, which will contain the `local.php` with its usernames and passwords.